# Condition base on Week of year (weekly changing method)

Tags: c#

Im going to deploy some conditional method that changed weekly.

for example This is my old code :

```
DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

            switch (dow)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                ///Do something
                    break;
            }
```

in above code if user calls my url in each day , it will get special answer based on that day.

now i wanna make another method like this :

```
         Condition week 1
         {
          //function 1 
         }
         Condition Week 2
         {
          //function  2 
         }
         Condition Week 3
         {
          //function  3
         }
         Condition Week 4
         {
          //function  1
         }
         Condition Week 5
         {
          //function  2
         }
         ..........
```

as u can see after week 3 i start to run/loop function 1 from start till week 6 , and this will continue

till end of year and after that.

should i achieve this goal by using "Calendar.GetWeekOfYear" ?

or should i use this method? :

```
      DateTime myDT = DateTime.Now;
      GregorianCalendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
      if ((myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) >= 1) && (myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) < 8))
      {
       Function 1
      }
      else if ((myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) >= 8) && (myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) < 15))
      {
       Function 2 
      }
      else if ((myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) >= 15) && (myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) < 22))
      {
       Function 3
      }
      else if ((myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) >= 22) && (myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT) < 31))
      {
       Function 1 
      }
```

Comment: Try both ways and see which one fits for you.

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for respond . for first one "GetWeekOfYear" , i cant found any solution. and for second one , the problem is after day 31 , if new month apear , it will start Function 1 again , instead of Function 2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GetWeekOfYear`.  It gives you some nice flexibility, how the first week is defined, and what the first day of the week should be.  Here's the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        Calendar calendar = dfi.Calendar;
        var week = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);

        Console.Write(week);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```